# Restrict What Can Extend a Class - Java

Tags: java, inheritance, spi

I'm designing an SPI, and the inheritance structure within it is a single tree. So as you can imagine, some classes are leaf nodes in the tree, some are not.

My problem is that I want to restrict this inheritance structure, allowing developers to only extend specific classes (mostly leaf nodes). By definition of the problem, I can't just declare earlier classes as `final`, or else the leaf node classes cannot extend them.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please show some code explaining your "context"

Answer (score 2):

You can put all parent classes in the same package as the "leaf" classes, making all those parent classes package-private in scope (don't declare them as public). This will restrict their visibility.

If you're lucky to use java 9, you can use modules in your project and only export the leaf classes.

Comment: That's a good approach. The issue I would run into here is that I used subpackages to structure it. Package private doesn't extend to subpackages. So I would have to completely flatten my package architecture into a single package. I suppose that isn't the end of the world.

Comment: Yep, you'd have to flatten your package tree.

Comment: Can you explain the java 9 statement? I don't understand it. This is a 1 man project, so I can switch from java 8 to 9 if I wish.

Comment: Check this dzone article, it would do the basic concepts more justice than would my comment: https://dzone.com/articles/java-9-modularity-jigsaw.